# Access violation reading location when using mongocxx driver

Tags: c++, mongodb, visual-studio, windows-7-x64, mongo-cxx-driver

I'm having some trouble with the mongodb c++ driver.

I have the following code and it worked fine:

```
//bsoncxx::document::value doc-->It was defined properly before

static mongocxx::instance inst{};

mongocxx::client conn{ mongocxx::uri{} };

auto db = conn["Test"];

auto res = db["Executions"].insert_one(std::move(doc));
```

But when I changed to:

```
static mongocxx::instance inst{};

mongocxx::client conn{ mongocxx::uri{} };

auto db = conn[dbName];

auto res = db[colName].insert_one(std::move(doc));
```

(dbName and colName are string parameters of a function)

When code reaches the line:

```
auto db = conn[dbName];
```

I get the following exception:

```
Access violation reading location 0x0000726F74636570
```

I'm using Windows 7 x64 and Visual Studio 2017

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really enough information here to know for sure, I'm going to take a wild guess and say that you are mixing the debug and release runtimes, such that `std::string` has a different layout between the internals of the compiled `mongocxx` library and your application.

It is very important that you build the driver once for each form of the CRT that you want to be able to use, and that your application select the correct one based on its current build configuration.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/md-mt-ld-use-run-time-library?view=vs-2017